# How can a member edit an entry via a Channel Form but save as a copy?

Tags: ee2, channel-form

I'm searching for a solution how a member can edit an entry on frontend, but it should not change the entry on submit, but instead it should create a new entry in the database?

Answer (score 1):

One option is to set up your channel form tags as if you're creating a new entry. Then use an embedded template to output the fields for your form using channel entries tags for whichever entry you're using as the form starting point.

So it works like you're creating a new entry, but have pre-filled the form from an existing entry. Like:

```
{exp:channel:form .... }

    {embed="some_template_group/some_template" use_entry_id="{segment_4}"

    <button id="form_submit" type="submit">Submit</button>
{/exp:channel:form}
```

and then on the embedded template:

```
{exp:channel:entries 
    entry_id="{embed:use_entry_id}"     
.... }

    <input type="text" name="title" id="title" value="{title}">
    etc....
{/exp:channel:entries}
```